# Compare fraction values present in a text file and outputting it based on a criteria

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a temp.txt file having the contents which is shown when `cat temp.txt` is used

0.3

1.3

5.3

7.3

They are obviously in string format but we need to compare it using arithmetic operators

Is it possible to read every line from the txt file and compare it with a fixed number (lets say 5.7). If that criteria is met I need to echo it out to the terminal saying that "Well this number is bigger than the thresold " and also output it to a another txt file.

Edit: Hope this clarifies

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Hint: This is very easy using `awk`. Now make an attempt and tell us where you're stuck.

Comment: I edited the question to show the real content of the file, but now it is a bit unclear what the OP wants. Could you clarify, please? And of course, post what were your attempts so far.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{ 
    if ($1 > 5.7)
        print "number " $1 " is larger than 5.7"
}' temp.txt | tee output_file.txt
```

If you need the threshold to be determined dynamically you can pass it as an argument to awk (google how to do this).

Edit: new format specified by op

```
sed 's/.*>\(.*\)<.*/\1/' temp.txt | sed '/^<[^>]*>/d' $awk '{ 
    if ($1 > 5.7)
        print "number " $1 " is larger than 5.7"
}' | tee output_file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

When you can use some c++ code with qt this should do it

programName treshhold inputfile outputFile

With qt it should be 10 lines.

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QString>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(argv, argc)
{
 QFile file(argv[2]);
 QString outFileName(argv[3]);
 QString argumentTreshold = argv[1];
 float treshHold = argumentTreshold.toFloat();

 file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly):

QString line;
 while(line = file.readLine())
 {
   float currentNumber = line.toFloat();
   if(currentNumber > treshHold)
   {
      std::cout << "Well this number " <<currentNumber << "  is bigger than the thresold " << std::endl;
      QString currentNumberString = QString("") + "echo " + QString::number(currentNumber) + " >> " + outFileName;
      system (currentNumberString.toStdString().c_str());
   } 
 }

 }
```

Comment: Programming languages are not the best way to go here I believe, many scripting languages will be able to achieve his goal in just a few lines.

Comment: I agree with you, but my bash-fu is weak :(. So I tried to help with a language where I am good at :).

Comment: Well taking a different approach is never bad of course, we could never object to too much help. And bash-fu? Nice one!

Answer (score 0):

awk with match

```
awk 'match($0,/>([^<]+)/,a)&&a[1]>5.7{print a[1]" is bigger than 5.7"}' file
```

If it has to be a list and in the format `N.N`

```
awk 'match($0,/li>([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/,a)&&a[1]>5.7{print a[1]" is bigger than 5.7"}' file
```